# Postfix relay outgoing email messages based on message size

Tags: linux, email, postfix, smtp, g-suite

I know that I can choose different transport agents (different SMTP servers) for different mail accounts. However, how to deliver messages larger than 10 MB using local SMTP server and smaller messages using an external service (e.g. Google SMTP servers)?

Is there any message size based transport policies? How to edit them?

**[more information]**

The reason I want to do this since the external email provider I use for email delivery limits outgoing messages' size to a maximum of 10 MB each so I want to send those large messages using my own SMTP servers while all others using the external service.

Comment: Mind [adding](https://serverfault.com/posts/1036961/edit) the problem you are trying to solve here to your question? What you propose is certainly achievable, but I wonder if the underlying problem has simpler solutions.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the ClamAV milter.  Scan outbound messages in the usual way, e.g.

```
smtpd_milters = unix:/var/run/clamav/clamav-milter
milter_default_action = accept
```

In the milter config, set

```
MaxFileSize 10M
AddHeader Replace
```

If the milter rejects the message, processing continues.  But the `X-Virus` headers will be different.  You can then use this header, e.g. in `header_checks`, for postfix to route accordingly.

Not entirely within postfix, so someone else might have a cleaner answer.